# How to pass computed value for column1 onto column2 in update

Tags: plsql

First of all, I am using plsql, and adapting an existing command. I probably would have done it differently from scratch.

I want to do something of this kind, but this doesn't work.

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME 
SET   COLUMN1 = FUNCTION1(...)
    , COLUMN2 = FUNCTION2(..., COLUMN1)
;
```

Ideally, I would like to avoid doing this

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME 
SET   COLUMN1 = FUNCTION1(...)
    , COLUMN2 = FUNCTION2(..., FUNCTION1(...))
;
```

Is there any way of achieving this, maybe by storing the computed value for COLUMN1 into a variable?
For example, in C, something like this would be possible.

```
COLUMN1 = VARIABLE_NAME = FUNCTION1(...)
```

Or maybe by positionally referring to it? This syntax doesn't work, but I have a vague idea that it might be possible.

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME 
SET   COLUMN1 = FUNCTION1(...)
    , COLUMN2 = FUNCTION2(..., {1})
;
```

Thanks.

Comment: This (from your 1st query): `COLUMN2 = FUNCTION2(..., COLUMN1)` is - actually - `COLUMN2 = FUNCTION2(..., NEW_VALUE_OF_COLUMN1)`, right? Not the "original" (old) COLUMN1 value. That's what your 2nd query suggests. If so, unfortunately, I don't have any better idea - currently, I think that 2nd query (the one you'd like to avoid) is the way to do it. I'd be happy if someone suggests something better; I'll keep an eye on this question and - hopefully - learn something new.

Comment: Yes. What I want a a better way of doing `COLUMN2 = FUNCTION2(..., NEW_VALUE_OF_COLUMN1)`

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this in PL/SQL then you can call the functions, assigned the return value to variables and then use those variables to update the table. Like:

```
 lv_col1 := function1(...);
 lv_col2 := function2(...,lv_col1);

    update table
       set column1 = lv_col1,
        column2 = lv_col2
```

This way you don't have to call the function1 multiple times.